# Prove that the sum of 2 bivectors in $R^{3}$ is a bivector? Hint:Think geometrically

Tags: linear-algebra

$R^{3}$ is noted as a 3 dimensional space. I know that pseudo-scalars are bivectors on a plane. 
 also I know bivectors have more freedom than scalars and vectors on a plane. 
 Can I use $a \land b$ + $c \land d$ to start off this proof?

Comment: What is the definition of bivectors you are starting with? Is it not already defined as a vector space?

Comment: From my knowledge, bivectors are parallelograms and $a \land b$ is a bivector

Comment: A bivector is actually a sum of such terms by definition. The ones you describe are called the simple bivectors. In higher dimensions, not all bivectors are simple.

Comment: Oh so what is the correct way to try and prove this?

Answer (score 1):

There is some redundancy in expressing bivectors with the symbols $a\wedge b$. It is possible that $a\wedge b=c\wedge d$ even if $a,b$ are different from $c,d$ (including up to sign). We can think of any bivector $a\wedge b$ as representing a 2D subspace with orientation determined by the basis $\{a,b\}$, but equipped with a scalar equal to the area of the parallelogram spanned by $a$ and $b$. Therefore, if $R$ is a rotation that stabilizes the plane spanned by $a$ and $b$, the rotation preserves the area of the parallelogram spanned by $a$ and $b$, so $a\wedge b=(Ra)\wedge (Rb)$.

(If we assume $a,b$ are L.I. and use a basis $\{a,b,\bullet\}$ in order to write an explicit formula for $R$, this fact can be checked explicitly with algebra.)

Therefore, to simplify a sum $a\wedge b+c\wedge d$ to a simple bivector, we note that the 2D subspaces spanned by $\{a,b\}$ and $\{c,d\}$ intersect in some axis $\ell$, then apply rotations $R$ and $S$ to $a,b$ and $c,d$ respectiely so that it looks like $p\wedge q+r\wedge s$ with $p\| r$ parallel. When they're parallel, they can be expressed as scalar multiples of a common vector, and then you can apply the distributive property for $\wedge$ only in reverse.

Comment: Ok so I have to use rotations and not use simple bivectors? I do not know of any difficult bivectors yet

Comment: @Zman What do you mean by "not use simple bivectors"? The problem is to simplify a sum of simple bivectors, $a\wedge b+c\wedge d$, into a single simple bivector, $x\wedge y$. I gave an explanation on how to do that.

Comment: oh. okay. my bad. I misinterpreted your statement

Comment: You also see how in higher dimensions this trick won't work because you can't find such an $\ell$ in general.

Comment: how can I prove that it wont work in $R^{4}$ or higher?

Comment: 2D subspaces don't necessarily intersect in 4D or higher.